# How to change the value of every column

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example i wanna change the value of  measurement_done column for every user

below is an example data how do i do so?

[image: Data I wanna change]

**Example code for how I update the value of a specific user**

**I wanna know how to update every users value**

```
 Students students = new Students(snapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class)
        , snapshot.child("section").getValue(String.class)
        , snapshot.child("teacherName").getValue(String.class)
        , snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class)
        , "no","yes"
        ,snapshot.child("subtraction_done").getValue(String.class)
        ,snapshot.child("division_done").getValue(String.class)
        ,snapshot.child("multiplication_done").getValue(String.class)
        ,snapshot.child("measurement_done").getValue(String.class));

dbRef.setValue(students);
```

Comment: So you need to update the value of `measurement_done`?

Comment: yes for every user not just a single specific user

Comment: @AlexMamo yes for every user not just a single specific user –

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). That screenshot is not conclusive.